# What is the meaning of this differential equation-ever thought about it?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Consider a differential equation $y'^2+xy\operatorname{ln}(xy'')=\sin(1/xy)$,what on earth does it actually mean.I mean consider $dy/dx=y$,it simply means that we have to find $y=f(x)$ defined on $\mathbb R$ such that $d/dx(f(x))=f(x)$.But what does the first differential equation mean.There we have an implicit and complicated relation between $x,y,y',y''$ etc and often the solutions to the differential equations are not an explicit function of $x$ such as $y=f(x)$.But we get some implicit solution $\phi(x,y)=0$.So what does it mean by the differential equation I mentioned in the beginning.It probably may mean that find $y=f(x)$ such that the expression holds.And its solution means all functions $y=f(x)$ such that $\phi(x,f(x))=0$.Am I right?
  Usually these differential equation courses are taught pretty mechanically without analyzing things as we do in case of real analysis or other pure maths topics.I want to study this differential equation with an analytic approach.Can someone help me.
  I would also accept any good reference books that might be helpful.

Comment: I think you might be interested in non-Newtonian calculus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_calculus The gist is that there exists more than one way to derive, even in $R \to R$; the classical derivative being based on addition as an operator. Exponentials and logarithms play a role in defining some of these alternate derivatives. It's a doozy I haven't been able to explore enough, but I think there's a chance this is (at least part of) what you're looking for. There's also Lie algebras and foliations to understand differential equations as (non-intersecting) subspaces of manifolds.

Comment: @TristanDuquesne Any book on Differential equation in analytic approach?

Comment: I'm probably not the best person to ask, since I'm still learning most of this. If you want to work on intuitions for differential geometry, I'd look up Math for Physics Handbook, and eigenchris. There's also Flammable Maths (from whom I learned the existence of non-Newtonian calculus). I have some books on the subject of foliations and differential equations in my list, but I won't know how good they are until I've read them, so I don't want to give you a false lead (might be unclear books, and not on analysis of differential equations). If they still interest you, just ask.